# Prove that $a^3 + b^3 + 3abc > c^3$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, factoring, geometric-inequalities

Suppose $a,b,c$ are the sides of a non-degenerate triangle. Prove that $a^3 + b^3 + 3abc > c^3.$

---

I was thinking that this inequality looked suspiciously like $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc,$ which factors as $(a + b + c) (a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2).$ However, I have little to no idea how to get that. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You can rewrite your inequality as $a^3+b^3+(-c)^3-3ab(-c)>0$. Can you end now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your hint we need to prove that: $$(a+b-c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab+ac+bc)>0.$$
Can you end it now?

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab+ac+bc=b(b+c-a)+a^2+c^2+ac>0.$$

Comment: I think I can, thanks so much!

Comment: @questionasker   You are welcome!

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience, but I'm not actually sure how to prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab + ac + bc > 0.$

Comment: @questionasker, what can you say about sign of $b+c-a$?

Comment: I think you should not be able to prove  2+2+2−++>0. If you proved this, then the final target is wrong.